# Any Apache Tajo based SaaS to try?

Tags: amazon-web-services, analytics, apache-tajo

Is there any Apache Tajo based service preferrably running out of AWS? I can easily set up a single node cluster for testing. But with multi-node cluster I can run more realistic testing and having some kind of Tajo SaaS would be so helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one. Visit http://taas.gruter.com/ .
And its provider also shared a readable link at http://www.gruter.com/products/taas/ .
Apparently it provides pre-configured Tajo AMI and web UI to setup multi-node cluster on AWS. Direct S3 access and runtime cluster resizing are also supported.